# Force show zero(0) value if now rows returns in cross tab

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Currently I have a few cross tabs setup with a sum of value, which is calculated off a given date range. Now this works great if both rows have values for the date range but it screws up the look of the report if one of the rows returns no values. SO what I would like to achieve is that if the rows returns now values (nothing found in date range) to return a zero ie

```
--------------------
Imported Stock | 12
---------------+----
Exported Stock | 0
--------------------
```

I would like to achieve the above example. unforutanitely all I will get in my crosstab is Imported Stock to appear.

For the calculated value I used a formula

```
if {Command.location} = 'London' then 1 else 0
```

any way I can get the exported stock to show zero even if no value is returned for a given date range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by building the whole system using text blocks and formulas

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the data field.  Go to Format Editor.  In Number Tab click Customize. Bottom Right option SHOW ZERO VALUES AS with a drop down option underneath.  Choose 0 rather than "Default Format"

Comment: Again this would work IF there were returned values. As pointed out in my original post, no records are returned, thus cannot change the values

Comment: Are you using a linked table for this report?